# rails4で２つの同じモデルをhas_manyで結びつけるには？

Tags: rails-activerecord

itemモデルを作成しuserモデルにmain_itemとsub_itemの２つのアイテムリストを結びつけようと思い、以下のようにしてみました。

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :main_items, :as => :itemable, :class_name => "Item"
  has_many :sub_items, :as => :itemable, :class_name => "Item"
end
```

そのあと、それぞれのitemsに要素を追加してみたのすが、内部的にmainとsubが指す要素が同一のものになってしまい、どちらか片方に要素を追加すると、もう片方にも要素が追加されてしまうという現象が発生しました。

```
# user = User.new
# user.main_items.new name:'sword'
# user.sub_items.new name:'shield'
# user.save
# user.main_item.count
=> 2
```

mainとsubのアイテムリスト独立してuserに結びつけたい場合には、どのようにすればよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main_item と sub_item でクラスを分けます。別のモデルを作成しても良いのですが、単一テーブル継承 (STI) を利用すると扱いやすいでしょう。ここでは、Item を継承して Item::Main, Item::Sub を作ります。

分かりやすいように、以下の例では User, Item いずれにも name というプロパティがあることを前提に書いてあります。

1. STIのためにマイグレーションを作成します。

   ```
   rails g migration AddTypeToItems type:string
   rake db:migrate
   ```

   type には所属するクラス名 ("Item::Main" または "Item::Sub" が入ります)
2. モデルをいろいろいじります。

   ```
   # app/models/item/main.rb
   class Item::Main < Item
   end
   ```

   ```
   # app/models/item/sub.rb
   class Item::Sub < Item
   end
   ```

   ```
   # app/models/user.rb
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :main_items, :as => :itemable, :class_name => "Item::Main"
     has_many :sub_items, :as => :itemable, :class_name => "Item::Sub"
     has_many :items, :as => :itemable
   end
   ```

   便利そうなので items でどちらの種類の item も取れるようにしておきました。
3. 試します。

   ```
   user = User.create name: "Fate"
   user.main_items.create name: "school uniform"
   user.main_items.create name: "barrier jacket"
   user.sub_items.create name: "pencil"
   user.sub_items.create name: "notebook"

   user.main_items.pluck(:id, :name)
   # => [[1, "school uniform"], [2, "barrier jacket"]]
   user.sub_items.pluck(:id, :name)
   # => [[3, "pencil"], [4, "notebook"]]
   user.items.pluck(:id, :name)
   # => [[1, "school uniform"], [2, "barrier jacket"], [3, "pencil"], [4, "notebook"]]
   ```

   よい感じですね。

ちなみに、Item として検索しても、Item::Main または Item::Sub のインスタンスが返ってきます。(User#items で取得した場合も同じ)

```
Item.find 1
# => #<Item::Main id: 1, name: "school uniform", itemable_id: 1, itemable_type: "User", created_at: "2015-01-23 15:58:26", updated_at: "2015-01-23 15:58:26", type: "Item::Main">
```

Comment: とても丁寧でわかり易い回答ありがとうございましたm(_ _)m